# How to use @ActivityInfo.ScreenOrientation

Tags: java, android, annotations

I try to create a method which returns me the screenorientation dependend on
wether the Device is a handheld or a tablet.

```java
public int getScreenOrientation(boolean isTablet){
    if(isTablet){
        return ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
    } else {
        return ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
    }
}
```

But when I use `setRequestedOrientation(getScreenOrientation));` I get a lint-error `Must be one of: ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_.........` which I can suppress, but that doesn't look like clean code.

So I found, that `getRequestedOrientation` uses the `@ActivityInfo.ScreenOrientation` Annotation. So I tried to use it myself:

```java
@ActivityInfo.ScreenOrientation
public int getScreenOrientation(boolean isTablet){
    .
    .
    .
}
```

But the IDE gives me an error stating that the Annotation `@ActivityInfo.ScreenOrientation` could not be found.  But it is declared public in the official-android-source.

Comment: I'm in the same situation and I really don't understand why I can't use `@ActivityInfo.ScreemOrientation`...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put the following comment above the annoying statement where the magic constant inspection for [@IntDef and @StringDef annotation](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/support-annotations) is triggered, for example:

```
//noinspection ResourceType
setRequestOrientation(lock);
```

Comment: I am not the biggest fan of suppressing the error but it works and it's better than writing 5 Lines of Code in every Activity. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try the annotation `@IntegerRes` instead. This should work fine for you since you are returning an integer resource attribute from android.R.attr.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/IntegerRes.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#screenOrientation

The example below is working for me without IDE errors or warnings.

```
@IntegerRes
public static int getScreenOrientationPref() {
    if(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("LockOrientation", true)) {
        int orientation = sharedPreferences.getInt("Orientation", Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        if(orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            return ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE;
        }
        else {
            return ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT;
        }
    }
    return ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this does not work. The ScreenOrientationValues are final ints and not resources. So the IDE will throw an error at every line != `return ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE` which is 0